# Does Sinch maintain messaging queue system internally?

Tags: android, sinch, android-sinch-api

I am implementing Sinch SDK in my Android application. I have observed one thing that after connecting sinch client if I turn off wifi(means now no internet connectivity is available) and I send 4 to 5 messages they are not sent (because on receiving side there are no messages received). As soon as, I turned my device wifi on and the android device gets connected sinch sends those pending messages.(because after connecting to the internet receiving side got those 5 messages which were sent earlier). My question is how does this happen. I mean does sinch maintain any internal queue system and for internet connectivity? Or there is something else is implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we do, we store it locally and sends it as soon as we can

Comment: May I know how those are being stored. I mean what classes are being used for this purpose?